# Served moved to GoDaddy and PHP Mailer is giving an SMTP error

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

Our Media Temple server was bought and migrated to GoDaddy and now my PHP Mailer is not working. Not sure what needs to be updated - have looked around and only found threads which were several years old.

error is:

> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Mailer Error
> (mail@domain.com) SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.SMTP
> server error: Called RSET without being connected

Code is:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4; 
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'domain.com.';
//$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; //SMTP connection will not close after each email sent, reduces SMTP overhead
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = 'user@domain.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->setFrom('user@domain.com', 'user@domain.com');
$mail->addReplyTo('user@domain.com', 'user@domain.com');
```

Comment: If the code worked before you moved to GoDaddy, you should contact them and ask about it. It's not uncommon that hosting services blocks common ports for sending emails, so they  can prevent spammers from using their servers. It's not something we can help out with though, since we're not them.

Comment: What did you do after you followed the link in the error messages and read [the PHPMailer docs about GoDaddy](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#godaddy)? Just because threads are old doesn't mean they are no longer applicable. GoDaddy has been bad for a very long time.

Comment: @Synchro Well to be honest I didn't even find that page you had, so it was quite helpful. The error I'm getting now is when it tries to send to Gmail I get the following error:

SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: username@gmail.com: : Relay access denied

Comment: Yes, that means that you're trying to send from an address that it doesn't approve of. I suggest you contact GoDaddy support, or find a host that doesn't get in the way.

Comment: It wasn't a great decision to move to GoDaddy. Their PHP and mail settings are notorious for being nearly impossible to get configured correctly.